# Extra space between two stacked elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, space

I am running into a problem. I have about a 60px extra space between Feedback and Coupons. Is there a way I can get rid of this extra space? I tried to make them stackable but that did not work for me. Sorry in advance about the unnecessary divs and such. This was my first time coding a website and lots of tags are weirdly named.

HTML

```
   <div id='coupons' >
      <a id="coupons" name='coupons'>
        <div style="float:left">  
          <img id='myImg' src="https://preview.ibb.co/jBYUxv/coupon1.png" id="i1" height="300px" width="600px">
          <div id="myModal" class="modal">
            <span class="close">×
              </span>
            <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
            <div id="caption">
            </div>
            <script>
              // Get the modal
              var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
              // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
              var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
              var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
              img.onclick = function(){
                modal.style.display = "block";
                modalImg.src = this.src;
              }
              // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
              var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
              // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
              span.onclick = function() {
                modal.style.display = "none";
              }
            </script>
          </div>
        </div>      
        <div id='pformat'>
          <p>COUPONS FOR YOU!
          </p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id='feedback'><a id="feedback" name='feedback'> 
        <h1>FEEDBACK</h1>
        <div class="container">
  <form action="/action_page.php">
    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">

    <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..">

    <label for="country">Country</label>
    <select id="country" name="country">
      <option value="australia">Australia</option>
      <option value="canada">Canada</option>
      <option value="usa">USA</option>
    </select>

    <label for="subject">Subject</label>
    <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Write something.." style="height:200px"></textarea>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form></div></a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
      img {
        position: relative;
        display: block;
      }
        h1 {
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-size: 60px;
            color: #1A66FF;
            font-style: italic;
            text-align: center;
        }
      h2 {
        position: absolute;
        top: 190px;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 65px;
        color: white;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-style: italic;
      }
      h3 {
        position: absolute;
        top: 265px;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 65px;
        color: white;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-style: italic;
      }
      h4 {
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-style: italic;
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 60px;
        top: 700px;
        color: #1A66FF;
      }
        h5 {
            font-weight: normal;
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 30px;
            font-family: 'hind';
        }
      #divp2{
        font-size: 20px;
        font-family: 'hind';
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
        margin-left: 150px;
        margin-right: 150px;
        color: #4d4d4d;
        top: 900px;
        margin-left: 150px;
        margin-right: 150px;
        font-weight: 0;
      }
      @font-face {
        font-family: 'hind';
        src: url('C:/Users/lakes/Desktop/hind2.ttf')
      }
      #pformat{
        text-align: center;
        margin-right: 30px;
        font-size: 55px;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        margin-left: 620px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 1450px;
        font-style: italic;
        color: #1A66FF;
        font-weight: bold;
      }
      #opaque {
        opacity: .2;
      }
      #divp {
        font-size: 20px;
        font-family: 'hind';
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
        top: 1075px;
        margin-left: 150px;
        margin-right: 150px;
        color: #4d4d4d;
      }
        #coupons {
            background-color: whitesmoke;
        }
        #coupons:after { 
            content: "";
            display: table; 
            clear: both; 
        } 
        #feedback {
            background-color: ghostwhite;
        }
      #myImg {
        border-radius: 5px;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: 0.3s;
      }
      #myImg:hover {
        opacity: 0.7;
      }
      /* The Modal (background) */
      .modal {
        display: none;
        /* Hidden by default */
        position: fixed;
        /* Stay in place */
        z-index: 1;
        /* Sit on top */
        padding-top: 100px;
        /* Location of the box */
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        /* Full width */
        height: 100%;
        /* Full height */
        overflow: auto;
        /* Enable scroll if needed */
        background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
        /* Fallback color */
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
        /* Black w/ opacity */
      }
      /* Modal Content (image) */
      .modal-content {
        margin: auto;
        display: block;
        width: 80%;
        max-width: 700px;
      }
      /* Caption of Modal Image */
      #caption {
        margin: auto;
        display: block;
        width: 80%;
        max-width: 700px;
        text-align: center;
        color: #ccc;
        padding: 10px 0;
        height: 150px;
      }
      /* Add Animation */
      .modal-content, #caption {
        -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
        animation-name: zoom;
        animation-duration: 0.6s;
      }
      @-webkit-keyframes zoom {
        from {
          -webkit-transform: scale(0)}
        to {
          -webkit-transform: scale(1)}
      }
      @keyframes zoom {
        from {
          transform: scale(0.1)}
        to {
          transform: scale(1)}
      }
      /* The Close Button */
      .close {
        position: absolute;
        top: 15px;
        right: 35px;
        color: #f1f1f1;
        font-size: 40px;
        font-weight: bold;
        transition: 0.3s;
      }
      .close:hover,
      .close:focus {
        color: #bbb;
        text-decoration: none;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      /* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
      @media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
        .modal-content {
          width: 100%;
        }
      }
        /* w3schools feedback form */
        input[type=text], select, textarea {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-top: 6px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    resize: vertical;
}

input[type=submit] {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: #45a049;
}

.container {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-right: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your CSS you can change the `margin-top` as you please. I'm assuming you want no whitespace in between.

```
h1 {
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-size: 60px;
            color: #1A66FF;
            font-style: italic;
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You use id='feedback' twice, once in a div and once in '<' a '>' tag. that's not causing you your problem but something you should fix.   On the h1 for feedback set margin:0 auto;

```css
img {
        position: relative;
        display: block;
      }
        h1 {
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-size: 60px;
            color: #1A66FF;
            font-style: italic;
            text-align: center;
        }
      h2 {
        position: absolute;
        top: 190px;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 65px;
        color: white;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-style: italic;
      }
      h3 {
        position: absolute;
        top: 265px;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 65px;
        color: white;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-style: italic;
      }
      h4 {
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-style: italic;
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 60px;
        top: 700px;
        color: #1A66FF;
      }
        h5 {
            font-weight: normal;
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 30px;
            font-family: 'hind';
        }
      #divp2{
        font-size: 20px;
        font-family: 'hind';
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
        margin-left: 150px;
        margin-right: 150px;
        color: #4d4d4d;
        top: 900px;
        margin-left: 150px;
        margin-right: 150px;
        font-weight: 0;
      }
      @font-face {
        font-family: 'hind';
        src: url('C:/Users/lakes/Desktop/hind2.ttf')
      }
      #pformat{
        text-align: center;
        margin-right: 30px;
        font-size: 55px;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        margin-left: 620px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 1450px;
        font-style: italic;
        color: #1A66FF;
        font-weight: bold;
      }
      #opaque {
        opacity: .2;
      }
      #divp {
        font-size: 20px;
        font-family: 'hind';
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
        top: 1075px;
        margin-left: 150px;
        margin-right: 150px;
        color: #4d4d4d;
      }
        #coupons {
            background-color: whitesmoke;
        }
        #coupons:after { 
            content: "";
            display: table; 
            clear: both; 
        } 
        #feedback {
            background-color: ghostwhite;
        }
      #myImg {
        border-radius: 5px;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: 0.3s;
      }
      #myImg:hover {
        opacity: 0.7;
      }
      /* The Modal (background) */
      .modal {
        display: none;
        /* Hidden by default */
        position: fixed;
        /* Stay in place */
        z-index: 1;
        /* Sit on top */
        padding-top: 100px;
        /* Location of the box */
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        /* Full width */
        height: 100%;
        /* Full height */
        overflow: auto;
        /* Enable scroll if needed */
        background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
        /* Fallback color */
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
        /* Black w/ opacity */
      }
      /* Modal Content (image) */
      .modal-content {
        margin: auto;
        display: block;
        width: 80%;
        max-width: 700px;
      }
      /* Caption of Modal Image */
      #caption {
        margin: auto;
        display: block;
        width: 80%;
        max-width: 700px;
        text-align: center;
        color: #ccc;
        padding: 10px 0;
        height: 150px;
      }
      /* Add Animation */
      .modal-content, #caption {
        -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
        animation-name: zoom;
        animation-duration: 0.6s;
      }
      @-webkit-keyframes zoom {
        from {
          -webkit-transform: scale(0)}
        to {
          -webkit-transform: scale(1)}
      }
      @keyframes zoom {
        from {
          transform: scale(0.1)}
        to {
          transform: scale(1)}
      }
      /* The Close Button */
      .close {
        position: absolute;
        top: 15px;
        right: 35px;
        color: #f1f1f1;
        font-size: 40px;
        font-weight: bold;
        transition: 0.3s;
      }
      .close:hover,
      .close:focus {
        color: #bbb;
        text-decoration: none;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      /* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
      @media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
        .modal-content {
          width: 100%;
        }
      }
        /* w3schools feedback form */
        input[type=text], select, textarea {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-top: 6px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    resize: vertical;
}

input[type=submit] {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: #45a049;
}

.container {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-right: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id='coupons' >
      <a id="coupons" name='coupons'>
        <div style="float:left">  
          <img id='myImg' src="https://preview.ibb.co/jBYUxv/coupon1.png" id="i1" height="300px" width="600px">
          <div id="myModal" class="modal">
            <span class="close">×
              </span>
            <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
            <div id="caption">
            </div>
            <script>
              // Get the modal
              var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
              // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
              var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
              var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
              img.onclick = function(){
                modal.style.display = "block";
                modalImg.src = this.src;
              }
              // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
              var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
              // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
              span.onclick = function() {
                modal.style.display = "none";
              }
            </script>
          </div>
        </div>      
        <div id='pformat'>
          <p>COUPONS FOR YOU!
          </p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id='feedback'><a id="feedback" name='feedback'> 
        <h1 style='margin:0 auto'>FEEDBACK</h1>
        <div class="container">
  <form action="/action_page.php">
    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">

    <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..">

    <label for="country">Country</label>
    <select id="country" name="country">
      <option value="australia">Australia</option>
      <option value="canada">Canada</option>
      <option value="usa">USA</option>
    </select>

    <label for="subject">Subject</label>
    <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Write something.." style="height:200px"></textarea>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form></div></a>
</div>
```

Comment: What problem would using both of those tags together cause?